# Combine multiple ParametricPlot3D to export to stl file (w/o using Show[])

Tags: export, parametric-functions, conversion

I have multiple ParametricPlot3D functions, that I am visualizing together using the Show[] operator. However, I cannot export this as an **stl** file

Some of my functions:

```
helix2 = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t] , Cos[t], t + k*Pi}, {t, -10, 10}]
L1 = ParametricPlot3D[{-0.544021111 + 1.542611823 l, -0.839071529 + 
0.892143075 l, 10 + 0 l}, {l, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Yellow}]
L2 = ParametricPlot3D[{0.412118485 + 0.082764213 l, -0.911130262 + 
1.780090051 l, 9 + 0 l}, {l, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Orange}]


DNA = Show[helix1, helix2, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6, L7, L8, L9, L10]
```

[image: DNA]

When I try to export to an stl file, this message pops up:

[image]

What can I do to put my graphic in a form so it will be able to export as an stl file??

Comment: What are `L3` through `L10`? `Show` should work. The fact that it remains blue suggests the graphic never got assigned to `DNA`.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: it seems to me that .stl files can't take a curve like `helix2` in the format, so you may want to consider converting it to a `Tube` or something.

For example, if I try `Export["helix.stl", helix2]`, I get "Export::nodta: STL contains no data that can be exported to the STL format.", but something like `Export["helix.stl", helix2 /. Line[pts_] :> Tube[pts, .04]]` works much better.

Comment: Interesting, you're right, I tried exporting one helix alone, one line alone, and it still didn't work. And L3-L10 are just more lines, they're not really relevant to the issue I'm experiencing. Thank you for trying